# React Native replace parts of string with tagged elements

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a sentence for example:

"How now brown cow"

I want to find certain words within the sentence, for example 'now' and 'cow' and have them generated with difference tags added around each word. For example:

```
<Text style={styles.text}>
How <TouchableHighlight><Text>now</Text></TouchableHighlight>brown<TouchableHighlight><Text>cow</Text></TouchableHighlight>
```

But I can't see how to add these element tags to them. The basic code is below:

```
render() {
   return (
  var sentence = "How now brown cow";
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._pressRow(rowID)}>
    <View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
        {sentence}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
);
},
```

Comment: did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 2):

- Split your sentence using [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) at **iterate through that array**.
- Make sure, that you change the [`flexDirection`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#flexdirection) to `row`, otherwise the single elements will be positioned in single lines.
- I added a **space after each word**, maybe you could look for a better solution, so that the space won't be added to the last element.

  ```
  render() {
    const sentence = "How now brown cow";
    const words = sentence.split(' ');
    const wordsToHighlight = ['now', 'cow'];

    const renderWord = (word, index) => {
      if(wordsToHighlight.indexOf(word) > -1) return (<TouchableHighlight><Text>{word} </Text></TouchableHighlight>);
      return (<Text>{word} </Text>);
    }

    return (<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>{React.Children.map(words, renderWord)}</View>);
   }
  ```